# Is it guaranteed that 'isspace' returns true for each one of the default delimiters of 'split', and only to them?

Tags: python, python-2.7, whitespace

I know that the `split` method uses white-space delimiters by default.

I would like to make sure that:

1. The `isspace` method returns `True` for each one of these delimiters.
2. There is no other character out there (Ascii, Unicode, etc) which is not included in these delimiters, yet `isspace` returns `True` on it.

In other words, are the methods `split` and `isspace` "fully aligned" on this aspect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just ran this code.

```
import sys
for i in range(sys.maxunicode + 1):
    c = unichr(i)
    assert c.isspace() == (len((u'foo' + c + u'bar').split()) == 2)
```

Comment: OK, can you please explain this magic number at the top? I assume that this is the total number of possible unicode characters, but is this a part of the standard?

Comment: @goodvibration See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unichr). It is the max unicode value 0x10FFFF plus 1.

Comment: BTW, I get `ValueError: unichr() arg not in range(0x10000) (narrow Python build)` on my env, so you might wanna reconsider that "1114112".

Comment: @goodvibration Your python is compiled with UCS-2, not UCS-4. I have updated the answer for that.